# what's the best practice to design an error code of a method?

Tags: java, c++, network-programming

since I don't have many in practice programming experience, I wonder that how to design an error code of method/function. For example, in java there is a method - string foo(int arg1, string arg2), the method return a string that can be null and it difficult to find a special string as the error code if the method can return string of any context. If the method is a RPC method, it is impossible to use exception to deal with error. So in this situation , what's the best practice to design an error code of a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it is an error, use `Exception`, `RuntimeException` for the ones that are unexpected like `a/0`, and checked exception otherwise.

Second, you may use a *wrapper*. For example,

```
class SomeWrapper{
    boolean isSuccess;
    String value;
}
```

Then the method can be `SomeWrapper foo(...)`

Comment: thank you. In situation of RPC, it is impossible to use exception. I think second way works.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot use exception, In C++, you may [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Then your method becomes:

```
boost::optional<std::string> foo(int arg1, std::string arg2);
```